# Postgres \copy from CSV: how to format range variables?

Tags: postgresql, psql, csv, copy, range-types

Consider a Postgres table containing a range variable:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (t_range tsrange, field1 text);
```

If I want to manually insert a row via `psql`, I can run:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (t_range, field1) VALUES ('[2014-06-02 07:00:00,infinity)'::tsrange, 'sometext');
```

Instead of inserting rows manually, I want to perform a bulk insert from a CSV file. I created a CSV file called `my.csv` using a similar format (using pipe as the delimiter to avoid having to escape the comma in the `tsrange` variable, and removing the explicit quote characters) with some content:

```
t_range|field1
'[2014-06-02 07:00:00,infinity)'::tsrange|'sometext1'
'[2014-06-02 07:00:00,infinity)'::tsrange|'sometext2'
```

Then from `psql` I ran

```
\copy my_table FROM 'my.csv' DELIMITER '|' QUOTE '''' CSV HEADER;
```

but this failed with the error

```
ERROR:  malformed range literal: "[2014-06-02 07:00:00,infinity)::tsrange"
DETAIL:  Junk after right parenthesis or bracket.
CONTEXT:  COPY my_table, line 2, column t_range: "[2014-06-02 07:00:00,infinity)::tsrange"
```

How should I format a CSV file with range variables for use with `\copy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the explicit cast to `tstrange` worked. The new CSV file looks like

```
t_range|field1
'[2014-06-02 07:00:00,infinity)'|'sometext1'
'[2014-06-02 07:00:00,infinity)'|'sometext2'
```

It seems to me that `\copy` is fine with automatically attempting to cast to the appropriate datatypes, but the explicit cast causes it to choke.

One can also simplify the CSV file a bit in this case by removing the quotes:

```
t_range|field1
[2014-06-02 07:00:00,infinity)|sometext1
[2014-06-02 07:00:00,infinity)|sometext2
```

and modifying the import command:

```
\copy my_table FROM 'my.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;
```